# My CSS Changes are not affecting my web pages in any way at all

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am having some issues with using Bootstrap for the first time. For some reason no matter what changes I make to my custom css it does not affect the bootstrap css or the regular html of the layout. I am currently trying to build my first website in visual studio and have been advised to work with bootstrap however I cannot seem to get it to work the way I want it to. I have successfully created web elements that I want without the use of bootstrap however when I try to use bootstrap it just does not want to display any of my custom css no matter what I do.

As I stated above, the first thing I tried was editing the bootstrap css directly, which had absolutely no effect on the layout of my webpages. After this, I discovered it was a good idea to create a seperate main.css file and then link it in to bootstrap file, with any changes being made to the main.css file should change the bootstrap css without having to mess up the bootstrap file. However, using this method none of the changes alter the way the webpages are displayed in any way. After this, I decided to follow this tutorial https://websitesetup.org/bootstrap-tutorial-for-beginners/ step by step, even though it is a notepad++ tutorial and not a visual studio tutorial. Even following this tutorial step by step none of the changes made to the css are displayed on the webpage.

When I simply add the html I want to the layout page without linking the bootstrap or main.css to the layout page the features work as intended, but I cannot customize some things with html so I need to get it working with css.

I have done a few google searches for solutions to this issue and tried several, such as moving code from the body of the layout page to the footer, ensuring the file directory for the .css files is correct, including capital letters, but I cannot seem to find where the issue is.

This is how I linked my layout page to the main.css file which contains the css for altering the nav bar of my webpages:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
  this is the link to the Main.css file with my custom .css that I used in the layout view in visual studio

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BSProject/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  This is the link to the bootstrap file I used when following the above tutorial and added this to the head of the index.html file

    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

This is the stuff I put in my main.css file, while also finding the .nav classes in the bootstrap.css and trying to put this information in the bootstrap file also.

```
/* The navigation bar */
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

    /* Links inside the navbar */
    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        /* Change background on mouse-over */
        .navbar a:hover {
            background: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        /* Main content */
        .main {
            margin-top: 30px; /* Add a top margin to avoid content overlay */
        }
```

I am trying to change the colour of the nav bar, the colour of the text, the colour of the text on scroll over, the colour of the text on the nav bar of the page that is currently being viewed, the text type/size/position and I want the nav bar to be fixed at the top of the page so that as you scroll down the page you can still see the nav bar at the top of the window. And I want the nav bar to scale with the size of the window for mobile users, a feature that is included in bootstrap. I understand everything I mentioned is not present in the above css, this is because I wanted to test it was functional before I began typing out all the css I need.

I can already do all of this without using bootstrap but for this project I am required to use it and I just can't seem to display anything other than the default bootstrap nav bar no matter what I change in the css.

Comment: can you please share your html body tag code.

Comment: This *could* be a matter of the order in which you're linking the CSS files and the cascade. By loading Bootstrap second — if your rules in `main.css` are the same level of specificity — the Bootstrap rules "win".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all move your `style` **Link** after **Viewport** and also move your custom css file `Main.css` after **Bootstrap.min.css**. Try this I hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
<head>  
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- StyleSheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BSProject/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">    
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, after reading/watching scores of tutorials none of them mentioned the correct place to put the link, they only mentioned it should be in the header, would have never known this if I didn't ask here